# Ionic card not moving back to side of web page

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've posted several questions recently and have had no answers. I'm beginning to wonder if I've been blacklisted or something. I'll try again with a new question.

I am working on an Ionic app with a desktop view. The initial page I am working on is not a card. It just has a list of settings on it. However, when you click one of the settings, a card appears on the right side of the screen, in a separate column. If I reduce the size of the window, at some point the card goes below the settings list.

The problem is that when I then increase the screen size again or even maximize it, the card stays below the settings list. It should show up again on the side of the settings list. Not sure how to make that happen though.

Here is the code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-list inset class="hovering">
            <ion-list-header><span class="settingsHeader">Settings</span> </ion-list-header>
            <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemTapped(item)" [ngClass]="{'highlightSelection': wasClicked}">
              <ion-icon name="create" item-left>
              </ion-icon>
              {{ item.label }}
            </button>  
          </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col *ngIf="this.addTable">
          <ion-list inset>
            <ion-list-header><span class="settingsHeader">{{ selectedItem.label }}</span>
              <button ion-button color="pm-yellow" (click)="addTapped($event, item)">Add</button>
              <button ion-button outline (click)="cancelTapped()">Cancel</button>
            </ion-list-header>
            <ion-card>
              <ion-card-content>
                <ngx-datatable #mydatatable class="ngx-datatable bootstrap material expandable" columnMode="flex" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="0" [rowHeight]="50" [scrollbarH]="false" [rowHeight]="50" [summaryRow]="false" [summaryPosition]="'bottom'" [loadingIndicator]="loading" [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns">
                  <div>
                    <ngx-datatable-column col-1 name="ID" [flexGrow]="1"></ngx-datatable-column>
                    <ngx-datatable-column col-2 name="Name" [flexGrow]="2">
                      <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
                        <span *ngIf="editRow != rowIndex">
                            {{ value }}
                        </span>
                        <input type="text"
                          autofocus
                          (blur)="updateValue($event, 'name')"
                          *ngIf="editRow === rowIndex"
                          [value]="value"
                        />
                      </ng-template>
                    </ngx-datatable-column>
                    <ngx-datatable-column name="Edit" prop="Edit" [flexGrow]="1">
                      <ng-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" ngx-datatable-header-template>
                        <span class="mobile-hidden"></span>
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template let-value="value" let-rowIndex="rowIndex" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                        <span class="mobile-hidden button-spacing">
                          <button ion-button small *ngIf="editRow !== rowIndex" (click)="storeOldValues(rowIndex)">Edit</button>
                          <button ion-button small outline *ngIf="editRow !== rowIndex" (click)="deleteRow(rowIndex)">Delete</button>
                          <button ion-button small *ngIf="editRow === rowIndex" (click)="doneEditing(rowIndex, false)">Save</button>
                          <button ion-button outline small *ngIf="editRow === rowIndex" (click) = "doneEditing(rowIndex, true)">Cancel</button>
                        </span>
                      </ng-template>
                    </ngx-datatable-column>
                  </div>
                </ngx-datatable>
              </ion-card-content>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can get better answers if you shorten your code and only keep the relevant parts.

Comment: I always have trouble figuring out what parts of the code people need to understand the project. I'm always providing too much or too little code. I'm still somewhat new to programming, so I'm still working on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running `content.resize()` after the window is resized, as exemplified below.

You can test by setting an event handler for window resize (not shown below).

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
 @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

 callThisAfterReducingSizeOfWindow() {
   this.content.resize();
 }
```

}

Comment: This isn't working for me. I put a console.log in there also to make sure the resizing method was firing, which it was, but the Ionic card still stayed below the settings list and just expanded to fill the window.